# ASP.NET MVC can't find route programmatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, global-asax, routes

I have the following one route, registered in my global.asax.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Home", // Unique name
    "", // Root url
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
        tag = string.Empty, page = 1 }
);
```

kewl. when I start the site, it correctly picks up this route.

Now, when I try to programmatically do the following, it returns NULL.

```
var pageLinkValueDictionary = 
    new RouteValueDictionar(linkWithoutPageValuesDictionary)
        {{"page", 2}};

VirtualPathData virtualPathData = 
    RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(viewContext, "Home"
        pageLinkValueDictionary);

// NOTE: pageLinkValueDictionary == 
//     Key: Action, Value: Index; Key: page, Value: 2
```

Why would this be happening?

I was under the impression that it would find the Home route but append any values not found as query string items?

### Update

Still no luck with this. Also, using the [MVC RC](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=f4e4ee26-4bc5-41ed-80c9-261336b2a5b6&displaylang=en), I now need to change the viewContext to veiwContext.RequestContext .. which compiles but I'm still getting a null result.

### Update 2

When I have the route without the `page=1` default item, the route *IS FOUND*.
eg.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Home",
        "",
        new { controller = "Post", action = "Index", tags = string.Empty }
    );
```

.. and `RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath` returns a `VirtualPathData` instance. When I add the `page=1` (default value) back in, the `VirtualPathData` instance returned is null?

Comment: I'm having this issue also, with asp.net-mvc3 and razor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the reason it returns null is because there is no route with a "page" route data.

Could you expand a little bit on what you are trying to achieve? If you want to redirect to a page with the url /page/2 or /?page=2 , then you should be using RedirectToRoute or RedirectToAction:

```
return RedirectToRoute("IndexDefault", new {page = "2"});
```

Comment: the reason why i can't use RedirectToRoute or RedirectToAction is because i'm trying to proramatically generate some <a href=... /> code. I don't really want to go to that page, but determine the HTML to goto that page.

Answer (score 1):

I think your route should be like this:

```
route.MapRoute("theRoute", "{controller}/{action}/{tag}/{page}",
  new { controller="Post", action="Index", tag="", page=1 });
```

or (depending on what the full URL should look like)...

```
route.MapRoute("theRoute", "/{tag}/{page}",
  new { controller="Post", action="Index", tag="", page=1 });
```

This will still match a request to http://mysite.com/ and go to your default route values defined above.  But now when you specify a tag or page, you'll get the url you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Phil's Route Tester:

[ASP.NET Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)

Comment: i've been using that and it's not helping :( It's really weird! tag is always string.empty and page is always 1 :(